# Problems in using the spreadtab and the ifthen packages

Tags: conditionals, spreadtab

Using the `spreadtab` package for some computing, I have to write an expression (mixing of literal and numerical expressions) if some conditions are true. Using the `ifthen` package, all works well for a simple condition but, if the condition involves a macro of `spreadtab`, it recognises it, compute it, gives it as true, and so writes the True condition, but only literal expression and doesn't make the wanted computing. How can I obtain the wanted condition in this case?

I give a MWE, with a simple condition. The first line of computation is what I want to obtain. It's well when the condition is simple `\equal{1}{1}`. When I use a condition based on the function `iflt` of `spreadtab` (what I must use !), `iflt(num1,num2,num3,num4)` is a test which gives num3 if num1 is lesser then num2 and gives num4 elsewhere, so we have `iflt(1,2,1,2)=1` and the condition `\equal{:={iflt(1,2,1,2)}}{1}` is true, and `\ifthenelse` recognizes it as true and writes the True condition, gives the numerical value for a2 and b2 but doesn't evaluate the sum given, (the command `:={a2+b2}`) and writes it as literal quantity. Spreadtab numerates the rows, a,b,c,... and the columns 1,2,3... so here a2=2 and b2=3 !

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
 @a &@ b    &@ a+b  &@  Test \\
\hline
 2  &3      &:={a2+b2}      &
 \ifthenelse{\equal{1}{1}}{The sum is  <<a2>>+<<b2>>=:={a2+b2}}{F}\\
\hline
 2  &3      &:={a2+b2}      &
 \ifthenelse{\equal{:={iflt(1,2,1,2)}}{1}}{The sum is <<a2>>+<<b2>>=:={a2+b2}}{F}\\
\hline
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]